# how to open only one window popup and restrict it to only one window

Tags: javascript, html, popup, popupwindow

I want to open only one popup window after clicking an URL.
but if i click the same URL another popup window is opening . so now there are two popup.

can anybody help on this issue as I want to restrict it to only one window.
Code:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var isOpen = "false";
var newwindow=null;
function call() {
    var link =document.getElementById('link').getAttribute('href');
    if (isOpen == "false") {
        isOpen = "true"; 
        window.open(link,'_blank','width=950,height=650,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
    } else {
        newwindow.location.href = url;
        newwindow.focus();
    }

}
</script>

<body>
    <a id="link" href="welcome.htm?hello=1" onclick="call()">Link 1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="welcome.htm?hello=1">Link 2</a>
    <br />
    <a href="welcome.htm?hello=asd">Link 3</a>
    <br />


</body>
```

Comment: *"can anybody help on this issue"* how can anybody help without showing your code.

Comment: @ketan . check the code

Comment: Your line ```<a id="link" href="welcome.htm?hello=1" onclick="call()">Link 1</a>``` does two things: first invoke your ```call()``` function, then follow the link. The call function opens the new window, but your original (initial) window gets reloaded with the href address. Let me suggest to use the alternative of simply defining href as: ```<a href="javascript:call('welcome.htm?hello=1')">```.

Comment: thanks Ramón its working ...  but the problem is after I open Link 1 and then I again click Link 3 its not opening .

Comment: Link 2 and 3 just reload the welcome.htm page on the current window, and your variables will be initialized again. You might keep your variables as long as the window is not reloaded. If you seek some inter-browser-windows communications, you shall consider other tools as cookies or [local storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Answer (score 2):

Give Name of the Window like:

```
window.open(link,'testName','width=950,height=650,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
```

It will open link in same window.

```
<script >
var isOpen = "false";
var newwindow=null;
function call() {
    var link =document.getElementById('link').getAttribute('href');
    if (isOpen == "false") {
        isOpen = "true"; 
        window.open(link,'testName','width=950,height=650,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
    } else {
        newwindow.location.href = url;
        newwindow.focus();
    }

}
</script>
```

Hope it helps. [Refer this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Answer (score 1):

This one works for me.

```
var win;

$(document).on('click','#button', function(event) {
    url = 'https://example.com/';

    if (!win) { 
        win = window.open(url, '_blank');

    }else{
        win.focus(); 
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function/code showing the popup shall make some change to mark that the popup has been already shown.

As an example: the following sample changes the link's `href` so the function does not get called again:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function myfunction () {
                document.getElementById("someid").setAttribute("href", "javascript:console.log('No more alert!')");
                alert("Will be shown only once!");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="someid" href="javascript:myfunction()">Click me!</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i given my code can u check it and see if it can be fixed.Actually its a popup window. the popup window should not be opened twice

Answer (score 0):

```
var newWindow = null;
goToUrl(url)
goToUrl = (url) => {
    if (!!!newWindow) {
        newWindow = window.open(url);
    } else {
        newWindow.focus()
        newWindow.location = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. You may want to improve it by adding more information about how this answers OP's question.